# Characteristic of a product ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let A and B be commutative rings with unity where char(A)=n and Char(B)=m s.t. n,m ∈ ℤ (and n,m ≠ 0). Prove or give counter example: if k ∈ ℤ<sup>+</sup> and n,m both divide k, then Char (A x B)| k.

Here was my thinking but I don't know if it is true: Char(A x B) = gcd(n,m) . I know that if n|k and m|k, we want to show that gcd(n,m)|K. However, I don't know if my initial assumption that Char(A x B) = gcd(n,m) is actually correct.

I know that a characteristic of a ring with unity is the smallest such n st 1*n≡ 0 where 1 is the multiplicative identity. 
I tried to use an easy example:

Char(ℤ<sub>12</sub>) = 12, Char(ℤ<sub>6</sub>)=6, Char(ℤ<sub>12</sub> x ℤ<sub>6</sub>) = 3 or does it equal 6???

Comment: It's the lcm, not the gcd.

Answer (score 2):

As you were told in the comments, $\mathrm{char}(A\times B)=\mathrm{lcm}(m,n)$. (To see why take a look at [Group Order and Least Common Multiple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/683560/group-order-and-least-common-multiple).) So the property you are looking for holds true.